# silverlight forms authentication heartbeat

Tags: silverlight, forms-authentication

I have a silverlight application protected by forms authentication.  I want the forms authentication to stay alive as long as the silverlight application is up.

I created a heartbeat web.service that silverlight calls.  In the web motheod I set a session variable.

However I am still having trouble with the forms authentication kicking in.

Any idea what might be causing it and what the best proactice for keeping forms authentication alive is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can turn on sliding expiration.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.slidingexpiration.aspx